# Umbraco - Trim last five characters in current page url

Tags: url, razor, umbraco, trim, truncate

Im getting the url of the current page using **@CurrentPage.Url**

It returns `http://hostname/abcdefgh/`

I wanted to trim out the last 5 characters of the URL

Req. URL `http://hostname/abcd` as the last five characters 'efgh/' is removed.

I tried using **@umbraco.library.TruncateString(testString,-5,"")** property to trim, but was unsuccessful.

Im new to umbraco. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Is it for creating a custom url for that node or... ?

Comment: Yes. It is actually useful when working with two websites of different seo URL in the same domain.

Comment: I don't understand it completely. So you have 1 domain but 2 websites?? Can you give some more details about this or some node structure of this?

Comment: Hi Miwaweb. Please check my comment for Matthew Allen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be interested to know the reason for doing this. Using the Remove method worked for me:

```
@{
    string url = CurrentPage.Url;
    url = url.Remove(url.Length - 5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mathew Allen. This is exactly what i was looking for. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Reason for me to using it is that im removing last 8 characters from the url say "/aboutus-arabic/" so it becomes "/aboutus". Then i add a "/" at the end which is the seo url for the english page. Hope i make some scene to you :)

Comment: If you have 2 pages one in english and one in arabic you can link these together on their id. Then you can easely get the other url by checking the relationship instead of manually edit the url.